# What converges this series?

Tags: calculus

What exactly converges the series?

$\sum _{k=3}^{\infty \:}\frac{2}{k^2+2k}$

I tried taking out the constant
$=2\sum _{k=3}^{\infty \:}\frac{1}{k^2}$

then $p=2,\:\quad \:p>1\quad \Rightarrow \sum _{k=3}^{\infty \:}\frac{1}{k^2}$

but I really don't know what i'm doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use partial fractions: Suppose

$$f(n)=\sum\limits_{k=3}^n\dfrac{2}{k^2+2k}=\sum\limits_{k=3}^n(\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{k+2})$$

$$=(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5})+(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6})+(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7})+\dots+(\frac{1}{n-2}-\frac{1}{n})+(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1})+(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2})$$

All the terms cancel out except four:

$$f(n)=\displaystyle \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}=\frac{7}{12}-\frac{2n+3}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

Obviously the last fraction converges to zero and you 're left with $\frac{7}{12}$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\dfrac{2}{k^2+2k}=\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{k+2}$. So our sum is 
$$\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{8}\right)+  \left(\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{9}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{10}\right)+\cdots.$$Remove the parentheses, and note the mass cancellations (*telescoping*). Almost everything dies, and we are left with $\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{4}$.

**Remark:** The above argument was informal. It can be replaced by a formal argument in which we take the sum $s_n$ of the first $n$ terms, and show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $ \dfrac{2}{k^2+2k}=\dfrac{(k+2)-k}{k(k+2)}=\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{k+2}$

So, $\sum\limits_{k=3}^\infty \dfrac{2}{k^2+2k}=\bigg( \dfrac13-\dfrac15\bigg)+\bigg(\dfrac14-\dfrac16\bigg)+\bigg(\dfrac15-\dfrac17\bigg)+\ldots$

Does this help?

Comment: You should only sum up to $N$, not $\infty$. As it stands now, you're writing a convergent sum as the different of two divergent sums, which is not correct.

Comment: @mrf Is there anyway to discard my edits?

Comment: @Rustyn I rolled it back for you.

Comment: @mrf thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: @mrf is the post okay now?

Comment: @HansLundmark is the post okay now?

Comment: No (as mrf explained).

Comment: @mrf is the post okay now?

Comment: @HansLundmark is the post okay now?

Comment: Now it's ok.${}{}$

Comment: @mrf thank you for helping out rectifying the mistake.

Comment: Well, now the statement is true, but on the other hand it doesn't prove anything about what the final result is... You should sum up to a *finite* number $N$, cancel terms, and only *then* let $N\to \infty$ to see what the limit of the remaining terms is.