# How to calculate $\sum_{k=1}^∞{\frac{1}{k(k+1)}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can you calculate sums such as:

$$\sum_{k=1}^∞{\frac{1}{k(k+1)}}$$

How do you best explain this to students in a rigorous or non-rigorous way?

Comment: This question seems to have been asked before.

Comment: Duplicate: [$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r(r+1)}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/7136/201168). Related: [$\sum\limits_{r=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(r-1)r(r+1)}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/124277/201168), [$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r(r+3)}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/588802/201168), [$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{r(r+2)}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/737816/201168), [$\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3r+1)(3r+2)}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/112161/201168). *(Found using the [Math.SE Index](https://mathindex.wordpress.com/other-series/))*

Answer (score 2):

You just do the actual work : by definition, $\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac 1{k(k+1)} = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^N \frac 1{k(k+1)}$. Computing the partial sums, you get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac 1{k(k+1)} = \sum_{k=1}^N \frac 1k - \frac 1{k+1} = 1- \frac 1{N+1}
$$
because this sum is telescopic (feel free to explicitly write the sum with $\cdots$ dots to your students or expand as a difference of two sums and shift indices). Therefore $\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac 1{k(k+1)} = \lim_{N \to \infty} 1 - \frac 1{N+1} = 1$.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 2):

**Less than rigorous:**

First note that $\dfrac 1 {12\cdot13} = \dfrac 1 {12} - \dfrac 1{13}$ and similarly for other consecutive integers.

So we have
$$
\left(1 - \frac 1 2 \right) + \left(\frac 1 2 - \frac 1 3 \right) + \left( \frac 1 3 - \frac 1 4 \right) + \cdots.
$$
Then $\dfrac{-1}2$ cancels $\dfrac{+1}2$, and $\dfrac{-1}3$ cancels $\dfrac{+1}3$, and so on.  Everthing cancels except the first term, which is $1$.

**Rigorous:**  Look at
$$
\left(1 - \frac 1 2 \right) + \left(\frac 1 2 - \frac 1 3 \right) + \left( \frac 1 3 - \frac 1 4 \right) + \cdots + \left(\frac 1{n} - \frac 1{n+1}. \right)
$$
We need $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ of that.  Everything cancels except $1 -\dfrac 1{n+1}$.  The essential point omitted in the less-than-rigorous version above is that the very last term approaches $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^∞{\frac{1}{k(k+1)}} = \sum_{k=1}^∞{\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}} = \sum_{k=1}^∞{\frac{1}{k}} - \sum_{k=1}^∞\frac{1}{k+1} = \sum_{k=1}^∞{\frac{1}{k}} - \sum_{k=2}^∞\frac{1}{k} \\\ \\
\begin{align}
= 1 &+ 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ⋯ \\
    &- 1/2 - 1/3 - 1/4 - ⋯ \\ \\\ 
= 1
\end{align} \\\ \\
$$

Comment: You should use the partial sums, not the infinite sums. The quantities you deal with after the first equality do not make sense -- it's $\infty - \infty$.

Comment: @ClementC. Considering that the OP asked for "a rigorous or non-rigorous way" to compute the sum, I think this answer is pretty good.

Comment: @zz20s I really don't see the point of doing this the "non-rigorous" way, since it is exactly the same proof as with the partial sums... but without correctness. What is the benefit then?

Comment: I agree with you, but that's something to take up with the OP.

Comment: @ClementC.: For the sake of explaining it to people far less experienced at mathematics than you. Sometimes I feel like people on this site have studied mathematics for so long that they've forgotten how confusing something like partial sums can be to a beginner.

Comment: @Zaz It may be an subjective issue, but I'd deem manipulations on indices of infinite sums **much** more confusing to anyone. For the partial sums, you can actually write down the terms on a board, one below the other, and cross them to show they cancel; and then taking the limit of $1-\frac{1}{N+1}$ is quite simple to grasp. $$
\begin{align}
 &\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2} \\
+ &\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3} \\
+ &\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4} \\
 &\vdots\\
+ &\frac{1}{N-1}-\frac{1}{N} \\
+ &\frac{1}{N}-\frac{1}{N+1} 
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

While exploitation of the resulting telescoping series after partial fraction expansion is a very simple way forward, I thought it might be instructive to present another way forward.  Here, we write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)}&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k \int_0^1 x^k\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}\,dx\\\\
&=-\int_0^1\log(1-x)\,dx\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

as expected!